# How can I compute double factorials in Perl?

Tags: perl, bignum

Given Wikipedia's discussion of [Double Factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Double_factorial)s, can anyone suggest where I might find a bignum version of this for Perl, or else suggest how it might be written?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl will handle whatever your C compiler can handle, for anything bigger you should be using [Math::BigInt](http://perldoc.perl.org/Math/BigInt.html).

I would recommend you read [perlnumber](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlnumber.html).

A definition for the double factorial (in perl golf):

```
sub f{$_[0]&&$_[0]>=2?$_[0]*f($_[0]-2):1}
```

Comment: I've been using BigInt. The issue is that BigInt doesn't have anything like a Double Factorial. It has `bfac` but that's a different beastie.

Comment: I thought you were after a number big enough to store the result, not a math library that would provide the operation.

Comment: @boost: You can easily write one for you.

Comment: @H.P.Y. Not wanting to make life /too/ easy I did provide one ;)

Comment: Scalar value @_[0] is better written as $_[0] in stackoverflow.com/questions/416377.  Golfing is fun, but golfing with warnings turned on is even better.  ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here are lots of alternative approaches to implementing [Fast Factorial Functions](http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/FastFactorialFunctions.htm). The Poor Man's algorithm may be a good choice for you, as it uses no Big-Integer library and can be easily implemented in any computer language and is even fast up to 10000!.

The translation into Perl is left as an exercise for the OP :-)

Answer (score 1):

Perl 5.8 and later come with the [bignum](http://perldoc.perl.org/bignum.html) package. Just use it your script and it takes care of the rest:

```
use bignum;
```

I talk about this a bit in [Mastering Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527242/) when I use the factorial in the "Profiling" chapter.

Answer (score 1):

Although dsm's answer is accurate, the *real* way to calculate factorials in Perl, regardless of whether you use dsm's algorithm (golfed or not) is to *[memoize](http://perldoc.perl.org/Memoize.html)* it. If you are going to call it with any frequency, you'll want to memoize any recursive mathematical function.

```
use Memoize;
memoize( 'fact2' );

sub fact2 {$_[0]&&$_[0]>=2?$_[0]*fact2($_[0]-2):1}
```

Comment: probably you want to edit that to 
 sub fact2 {$_[0]&&$_[0]>=2?$_[0]*fact2($_[0]-2):1}