# C++ program to calculate quotients of large factorials

Tags: c++

How can I write a c++ program to calculate large factorials.

Example, if I want to calculate (100!) / (99!), we know the answer is 100, but if i calculate the factorials of the numerator and denominator individually, both the numbers are gigantically large.

Comment: It sounds to me like you are actually trying to *avoid* calculating large factorials.

Comment: You can find several answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416483/how-to-find-a-factorial

Comment: What is your question?  Are you asking how to do arithmetic with large numbers, or are you asking how to calculate as many formulas as possible without anything bigger than `long` or `long long`?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966077/calculate-the-factorial-of-an-arbitrarily-large-number-showing-all-the-digits

Answer (score 15, accepted):

expanding on Dirk's answer (which imo is the correct one):

`#include "math.h"
#include "stdio.h"
int main(){
  printf("%lf\n", (100.0/99.0) * exp(lgamma(100)-lgamma(99)) );
}`

try it, it really does what you want even though it looks a little crazy if you are not familiar with it. Using a bigint library is going to be wildly inefficient.  Taking exps of logs of gammas is super fast.  This runs instantly.

The reason you need to multiply by 100/99 is that gamma is equivalent to n-1! not n!. So yeah, you could just do exp(lgamma(101)-lgamma(100)) instead. Also, gamma is defined for more than just integers.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Gamma function instead, see [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) which also pointers to code.

Answer (score 5):

Of course this particular expression should be optimized, but as for the title question, I like [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) because it offers a decent C++ interface, and is readily available.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gmpxx.h>

mpz_class fact(unsigned int n)
{
        mpz_class result(n);
        while(n --> 1) result *= n;
        return result;
}

int main()
{
        mpz_class result = fact(100) / fact(99);
        std::cout << result.get_str(10) << std::endl;
}
```

compiles on Linux with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -o test test.cc  -lgmpxx -lgmp`

Answer (score 2):

By the sounds of your comments, you also want to calculate expressions like 100!/(96!*4!).

Having "cancelled out the 96", leaving yourself with (97 * ... * 100)/4!, you can then keep the arithmetic within smaller bounds by taking as few numbers "from the top" as possible as you go. So, in this case:

```
i = 96
j = 4
result = i
while (i <= 100) or (j > 1)
    if (j > 1) and (result % j == 0)
        result /= j
        --j
    else
        result *= i
        ++i
```

You can of course be cleverer than that in the same vein.

This just delays the inevitable, though: eventually you reach the limits of your fixed-size type. Factorials explode so quickly that for heavy-duty use you're going to need multiple-precision.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to do so:

http://www.daniweb.com/code/snippet216490.html

The approach they take is to store the big #s as a character array of digits.

Also see this SO question: [Calculate the factorial of an arbitrarily large number, showing all the digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966077/calculate-the-factorial-of-an-arbitrarily-large-number-showing-all-the-digits)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a big integer library like [gmp](http://gmplib.org/) which can handle arbitrarily large integers.

Answer (score 1):

The only optimization that can be made here (considering that in `m!/n!` `m` is larger than `n`) means crossing out everything you can before using multiplication.

If `m` is less than `n` we would have to swap the elements first, then calculate the factorial and then make something like `1 / result`. Note that the result in this case would be double and you should handle it as double.

Here is the code.

```
   if (m == n) return 1;

   // If 'm' is less than 'n' we would have
   // to calculate the denominator first and then
   // make one division operation
   bool need_swap = (m < n);
   if (need_swap) std::swap(m, n);

   // @note You could also use some BIG integer implementation, 
   // if your factorial would still be big after crossing some values

   // Store the result here
   int result = 1;
   for (int i = m; i > n; --i) {
      result *= i;
   }

   // Here comes the division if needed
   // After that, we swap the elements back
   if (need_swap) {
      // Note the double here
      // If m is always > n then these lines are not needed
      double fractional_result = (double)1 / result;
      std::swap(m, n);
   }
```

Also to mention (if you need some big int implementation and want to do it yourself) - the best approach that is not so hard to implement is to treat your int as a sequence of blocks and the best is to split your int to series, that contain 4 digits each.

Example: `1234 | 4567 | 2323 | 2345 | ...`. Then you'll have to implement every basic operation that you need (sum, mult, maybe pow, division is actually a tough one).

Answer (score 0):

To solve x!/y! for x > y:

```
int product = 1;
for(int i=0; i < x - y; i ++)
{
    product *= x-i;
}
```

If y > x switch the variables and take the reciprocal of your solution.

Comment: this doesn't work Permutations and combinations. Example, nPr and nCr

Comment: Works fine for the example, fails for many, many other examples.
Try 100!/7!. The question was: "How to calculate large factorials?"

Btw, you should make product = 1 in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question, and got some pointers to some libraries:

[How can I calculate a factorial in C# using a library call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495856/how-can-i-calculate-a-factorial-in-c-using-a-library-call)

It depends on whether or not you need all the digits, or just something close.  If you just want something close, [Stirling's Approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) is a good place to start.