# Which data type or data structure to choose to calculate factorial of 100?

Tags: java, c, data-structures

I thought of writing a program to evaluate factorial of a given integer.

Following basics I wrote the below code in java :

```
long fact(int num){
if(num == 1)
 return 1;
else
 return num*fact(num-1);
}
```

But then I realized that for many integer input the result may not be what is desired and hence for testing directly gave input as 100.

My doubt was true as Result I got was "0"(cause result might be out of range of long).

So,I am just curious and eager to know as how may I make my program work for inputs<=150.

I would appreciate any valid solution in C programming language or Java.

Comment: The [pi or gamma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) functions might be of interest.

Comment: Abhinav nice question :)

Comment: I would compute the prime factorization and print that out, who wants to just read 100s of digits and marvel at them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**BigInteger** is your class. It can store **integers of** seemingly **any size**.

```
    static BigInteger fact(BigInteger num) {
        if (num.equals(BigInteger.ONE))
            return BigInteger.ONE;
        else
            return num.multiply(fact(num.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)));
    }
```

Comment: I concur. I bet that if you try to store a number exceeding the size of the memory it will fail. (But, +1!)

Comment: My edit isn't correct too, there is an infinite number of integers... Any ideas?

Comment: 'Seemingly' seems better, but I'm not a native English speaker.

Comment: @11684 +1 for thinking of that :)

Comment: You given nice answer, I think 10 like give you nice tag :)

Answer (score 4):

If you're not after a naive approach of factorial computation, you should do some research into the problem. Here's a good overview of some algorithms for computing factorials: http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/conclusions.html

But like the other answers suggest, your current problem is that you need to use a large number implementation (e.g. BigInt) instead of fixed size integers.

Answer (score 3):

In C Language, you can use array to store factorial of large number.
my reference: [*Calculate the factorial of an arbitrarily large number, showing all the digits*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966077/calculate-the-factorial-of-an-arbitrarily-large-number-showing-all-the-digits?answertab=votes#tab-top). it very helpful post.
I made small changes in code to convert into C.

```
int max = 5000;
void factorial(int arr[], int n){//factorial in array
    if (!n) return;
    int carry = 0;
    int i=max-1;
    for (i=max-1; i>=0; --i){
        arr[i] = (arr[i] * n) + carry;
        carry = arr[i]/10;
        arr[i] %= 10;
    }
    factorial(arr,n-1);
}
void display(int arr[]){// to print array
    int ctr = 0;
    int i=0;
    for (i=0; i<max; i++){
        if (!ctr && arr[i])      
            ctr = 1;
        if(ctr)
            printf("%d", arr[i]);
    }
}
int main(){
    int *arr = calloc(max, sizeof(int));
    arr[max-1] = 1;
    int num = 100;
    printf("factorial of  %d is: ",num);
    factorial(arr,num);
    display(arr);
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

And its working for 100! see: [here Codepad](http://codepad.org/8PMbUnNW)

I would like to give you links of two more useful posts.
1) [*How to handle arbitrarily large integers*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310276/how-to-handle-arbitrarily-large-integers) suggests `GPU MP`
2) [*C++ program to calculate large factorials*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731459/c-program-to-calculate-large-factorials)

Comment: This will not help at all 100! is way more than 8 byte.

Comment: I believe you can even do `long long`, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: @11684 ` unsigned long long int ll;` is also 8 bytes :(

Comment: I tried testing your code, calculating 5! and printing the results.  Output: `0000000000`.

Comment: @djechlin Yes working [see here for 5!](http://codepad.org/NFSM50qd). For 100! check my updated answer :)

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Strandjev 100! not only 8 byte. I just come to know its bigger than a BIG :P link: [**100! C Code**](http://codepad.org/8PMbUnNW)

Answer (score 0):

In java you have the BigInteger that can store arbitrary big integers. Unfortunately there is no equivelent in `C`. You either have to use a third-party library or to implement big integers on your own. Typical approach for this is to have a dynammically-allocated array that stores each of the digits of the given number in some numeric system(usually base more than 10 is chosen so that you reduce the total number of digits you need).

Comment: How would you represent a hexadecimal number with an array? An array of unions, either chars (for a-f) or int (for 0-9)?

Comment: @11684 for this particular problem I would use way bigger base than 16, but in the general case it is better to use as small type ass possible that would fit the square of the greatest value of a digit in the given numeric system. For hexadecimal number I would use unsigned char type.

Answer (score 0):

A decimal (base 10) digit takes about 3.3 bits (exactly: log(10)/log(2)). 100! is something like 158 digits long, so you need 158 * 3.3 = 520 bits.

There is certainly no built in type in C that will do this. You need some form of special library if you want every digit in the factorial calculation to be "present".

Using `double` would give you an approximate result (this assumes that `double` is a 64-bit floating point value that is IEEE-754 compatible, or with similar range - the IEEE-754 `double` format will give about 16 decimal digits (52 bits of precision, divided by the log(10)/log(2) like above). I believe there are more than 16 digits in this value, so you won't get an exact value, but it will calculate some number that is within a 10 or more digits.