# Specifying number of bits for a datatype in C

Tags: c, size

Is it possible to specify a datatype such as int or long to be able to store larger number of bits than it usually supports?

Example int supports 32 bits and long supports 64 bits. What if I want a long to support 128 bits or greater? Is it possible without the help of any libraries?

Comment: A similar question will help you, [Which data type or data structure to choose to calculate factorial of 100?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205587/which-data-type-or-data-structure-to-choose-to-calculate-factorial-of-100/15205645#15205645) Read my answer I writen a code in C

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the simplest way of implementing bigint in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340511/what-is-the-simplest-way-of-implementing-bigint-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible in C. You have to use some libraries like Bigint to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

[gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html) supports built-in `__int128_t` and `__uint128_t` types on 64-bit platforms.

Answer (score 0):

C is designed to give you a slight abstraction beyond the bare bones of the hardware you are operating on.  Because of this, the types that are commonly available correspond to data types the CPU can operate on natively.

Large integer types require multiple CPU instructions to perform basic operations on, and are therefor not native operations and not a part of the core C language.

That's not a rigid definition of C, but it's a reasonable general description of the general gist of the design decisions.