# My unsigned long long int return 0, help me

Tags: c, long-integer

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long int factorial(unsigned long long int n);

int main(void){
    unsigned long long int n;
    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    for(int i = 0; i < t; i++){
        scanf("%lld", &n);
        long int a = factorial(n);
        printf("%lld\n", a);
    }
}

unsigned long long int factorial(unsigned long long int n){
    if(n == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return (n * factorial(n - 1));
    }
}
```

I'm trying to print the factorial of 100, even using long long int it doesn't work, what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You're overflowing your data structure size. See [Which data type for calculating large factorials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205587/which-data-type-or-data-structure-to-choose-to-calculate-factorial-of-100/15205645#15205645).

Comment: `long int a` -> `long long int a`

Comment: try to use `double` instead of `long long int`. It should be large enough to handle `100!` but you may observe some small rounding errors (~1e-15 relative)

Comment: I have some doubts that it works up to 49!

Comment: `long long int` usually can represent integers up to `2^63-1`.  Still much too small for `100!`.  C doesn't have an integer type that can do it, so you'll need to start getting more creative.

Comment: @tstanisl `double` is 8 byte under windows

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин `double` is 8-byte on all platforms that use IEEE-754 double precision

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17039284

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%lld", &n);`  This should give a compiler message because `n` is UNSIGNED,  Suggest: `scanf("%ulld", &n);`  Notice the `u` for unsigned

Comment: regarding: `long int a = factorial(n);`  the function: factorial()` returns a `unsigned long long int`, NOT a `long int`