# Combinatory issue due to Factorial overflow

Tags: java, c#, math

I need a function which can calculate the [mathematical combination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic) of (n, k) for a card game.

My current attempt is to use a function based on usual Factorial method :

```
    static long Factorial(long n)
    {
        return n < 2 ? 1 : n * Factorial(n - 1); 
    }

    static long Combinatory(long n , long k )
    {
        return Factorial(n) / (Factorial(k) * Factorial(n - k)); 
    }
```

It's working very well but the matter is when I use some range of number (n value max is 52 and k value max is 4), it keeps me returning a wrong value. E.g :

```
   long comb = Combinatory(52, 2) ; // return 1 which should be actually 1326
```

I know that it's because I overflow the long when I make Factorial(52) but the range result I need is not as big as it seems.

Is there any way to get over this issue ?

Comment: You're looking to calculate binomials. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495856/how-can-i-calculate-a-factorial-in-c-sharp-using-a-library-call

Comment: Why did you tag this with both C# and Java?

Comment: @p.s.w.g : because both codes compile in Java and C#, and long are both 64bits.

Comment: I'm curious about why you need to calculate such large numbers.  Would an approximation suffice?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of using the default combinatory formula `n! / (k! x (n - k)!)`, use the recursive property of the combinatory function.

```
    (n, k) = (n - 1, k) + (n - 1, k - 1)
```

Knowing that : `(n, 0) = 1` and `(n, n) = 1`.

**-> It will make you avoid using factorial and overflowing your long.**

Here is sample of implementation you can do :

```
 static long Combinatory(long n, long k)
    {
        if (k == 0 || n == k )
            return 1;

        return Combinatory(n - 1, k) + Combinatory(n - 1, k - 1); 
    }
```

---

**EDIT : With a faster iterative algorithm**

```
    static long Combinatory(long n, long k)
    {
        if (n - k < k)
            k = n - k;

        long res = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i <= k; ++i)
        {
            res = (res * (n - i + 1)) / i;
        }

        return res;
    }
```

Comment: This is *super* inefficient, and with the numbers hes talking about, he likely still won't be able to actually compute the values that he'll need to.  This is like the textbook example of how not to use recursion.

Comment: @Servy, also a textbook example of when to use memoization.  Also could exploit the identity (n, k) = (n, n-k)

Comment: Yes because 4! still isn't that big of a number, but as soon as you get to about 8 you get to the point where it takes a very long time, and only a few past that if you can wait for quite some time.  That's the problem with having an O(N!) algorithm.

Comment: @jameslarge yes, that is one possible way of making this not perform terribly.

Comment: @Servy : I made an edit on the answer. I hope it will satisfy you

Comment: Than you for your answer

Answer (score 2):

In C# you can use BigInteger (I think there's a Java equivalent).

e.g.:

```
static long Combinatory(long n, long k)
{
    return (long)(Factorial(new BigInteger(n)) / (Factorial(new BigInteger(k)) * Factorial(new BigInteger(n - k))));
}

static BigInteger Factorial(BigInteger n)
{
    return n < 2 ? 1 : n * Factorial(n - 1);
}
```

You need to add a reference to `System.Numerics` to use BigInteger.

Comment: Than you for your answer

Comment: Java has a BigInteger class, but it doesn't have operator overloading, so you'd need to adjust `/`, `<`, `*`, and `-`.

Answer (score 2):

If this is not for a homework assignment, there is an efficient implementation in Apache's commons-math package

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/util/ArithmeticUtils.html#binomialCoefficientDouble%28int,%20int%29

If it is for a homework assignment, start avoiding factorial in your implementation.

Use the property that (n, k) = (n, n-k) to rewrite your choose using the highest value for k.

Then note that you can reduce n!/k!(n-k)! to n * n-1 * n-2 .... * k / (n-k) * (n-k-1) ... * 1 means that you are multiplying every number from [k, n] inclusive, then dividing by every number [1,n-k] inclusive.

```
// From memory, please verify correctness independently before trusting its use.
//
public long choose(n, k) {
  long kPrime = Math.max(k, n-k);
  long returnValue = 1;
  for(i = kPrime; i <= n; i++) {
    returnValue *= i;
  }
  for(i = 2; i <= n - kPrime; i++) {
    returnValue /= i;
  }
  return returnValue;
}
```

Please double check the maths, but this is a basic idea you could go down to get a reasonably efficient implementation that will work for numbers up to a poker deck.

Answer (score 0):

The recursive formula is also known as [Pascal's triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_triangle), and IMO it's the easiest way to calculate   combinatorials. If you're only going to need C(52,k) (for 0<=k<=52) I think it would be best to fill a table with them at program start. The following C code fills a table using this method:

```
static  int64_t*    pascals_triangle( int N)
{
int n,k;
int64_t*    C = calloc( N+1, sizeof *C);
    for( n=0; n<=N; ++n)
    {   C[n] = 1;
        for( k=n-1; k>0; --k)
        {   C[k] += C[k-1];
        }
    }
    return C;
}
```

After calling this with N=52, for example returns, C[k] will hold C(52,k) for k=0..52